# jquery target=_blank doesnt work

Tags: jquery, attributes, target

I have this piece of code:

```
$('.tool li a:first-child').each(function(){
        $(this).after(' <a href="' + $(this).attr('href') + '" title="Open link in new tab"><img src="/img/icon-arrow.png" height="9" width="9" alt="Arrow Icon" target="_blank" /></a>');
    });
```

So even though the images that are added are hyperlinked with a target=_blank, the link does not open in a new window.

Any thoughts why the browser does not recognize that?

-Ryan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the `target` attribute on the `a` tag, not the `img` tag.

```
$('.tool li a:first-child').each(function(){
    $(this).after('<a href="' + $(this).attr('href') + '" title="Open link in new tab" target="_blank"><img src="/img/icon-arrow.png" height="9" width="9" alt="Arrow Icon" /></a>');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

target="_blank" should be an attribute for the anchor tag

Replace:

```
$(this).after(' <a href="' + $(this).attr('href') + '" title="Open link in new tab"><img src="/img/icon-arrow.png" height="9" width="9" alt="Arrow Icon" target="_blank" /></a>');
```

With:

```
$(this).after(' <a href="' + $(this).attr('href') + '" target="_blank" title="Open link in new tab"><img src="/img/icon-arrow.png" height="9" width="9" alt="Arrow Icon" /></a>');
```